# Power series solution for differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Is the solution to differential equations using power series applicable only to homogeneous differential equations?
I mean equations of the form: $$a_2 \phi ''(x)+a_1 \phi '(x)+ \phi(x) = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

If you have a source term $f$ that admits a power series decomposition, you can apply the power series method to find a solution of your equation.

Also, this method can be extended to differential equations of any degrees. It also works if your coefficient $a_i$ are in the form $a_i x_k$ for any $k$.

Finaly, I would add that you need to be careful with this method if you have a non-linear O.D.E.

Comment: It's always applicable.

Comment: I can find the solution to this and equation and use them as homogeneous solutions to yield the particular solution using variation of parameters